# How send mail with vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, email-attachments

i need to send a file attached to an email that must be setn to specific user through smtp server with auth. How can i do that in vbscript?
Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://piquestecnicos.com/2018/08/script-para-envio-de-emails/) you can see an example. He shows the code for two different servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *no* experience with vbscript of VB for that matter... But a quick Google gave me [this result](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm) - it looks simple enough.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just take a look here:

[how to send an email with attachment in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962511/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-in-vb-net)

Try the following:

```
Dim oMsg As System.Web.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Web.Mail.MailMessage() 

oMsg.From = "noone@nobody.com" 
oMsg.To = "someone@somewhere.com" 
oMsg.Subject = "Email with Attachment Demo" 
oMsg.Body = "This is the main body of the email" 
Dim oAttch As MailAttachment = New MailAttachment("C:\myattachment.zip") 
oMsg.Attachments.Add(oAttch) 
SmtpMail.Send(oMsg)
```

Comment: VB.NET is not the same as VBScript .