# Need help figuring out how to add an attachment to an email in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm struggling to figure out how to go about adding an attachment to an e-mail in VB.NET. Here is my code so far and I'm not sure how to include the attachment. It's my first time working with the command prompt and the email system.

```
    Imports System.Net.Mail
```

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim client As New SmtpClient
    Dim email As New MailMessage
    Dim seconds As Integer
    Dim interval As Integer
    Dim ip As String = 0
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim desktop As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    input(seconds, interval, ip, counter)
    ping(interval, ip, desktop, counter)
    Console.WriteLine("Program successfully executed.")
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
Sub input(ByRef seconds As Integer, ByRef interval As Integer, ByRef ip As String, ByRef counter As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of seconds you would like between pings.")
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter no fewer than five seconds.")
    seconds = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    interval = seconds * 1000
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the IP you will be pinging.")
    ip = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to ping?")
    counter = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
End Sub
Sub ping(ByVal interval As Integer, ByVal ip As String, ByVal desktop As String, ByRef counter As Integer)
    Do Until counter = 0
        Process.Start("CMD", "/c ping " & ip & " >> " & desktop & "\log.txt")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval)
        counter = counter - 1
    Loop
End Sub
Sub email(ByRef client As SmtpClient, ByRef email As MailMessage, ByVal desktop As String)
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("fakebusiness01@gmail.com", "*****")
    client.Port = 587
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    email = New MailMessage()
    email.From = New MailAddress("fakebusiness01@gmail.com")
    email.To.Add("genericmail01@gmail.com")
    email.Subject = "Ping Results"
    email.IsBodyHtml = False
    email.Body = "The pings were successful, attached is the ping log."

    client.Send(email)
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: The documentation for the `Attachment` class has a code example.  It's in C# but it's pretty easy to read.  If you're not 100% sure then use an online converter to convert it to VB.  There's nothing difficult in it: create an `Attachment` object, call an `Add` method, call `Dispose`.  That's it.

Comment: Here is a great example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962511/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-in-vb-net

Comment: Well then, that was pretty obvious. I feel like an idiot for not figuring that out!

Thank you guys for the help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the property `Attachments` in your `MailMessage` object. You only need to check whether the file to be attached exists to avoid any exception, as below;

```
 Dim sFile as String = "Full_File_Path"
 Dim Attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(sFile)

  If IO.File.Exists(sFile) Then _
    email.Attachments.Add(Attachment)
```

In case you are attaching more than one files;

```
' Assuming AttachmentFiles is an ArrayList holding your files
Dim iCountFiles as integer

 If AttachmentFiles IsNot Nothing Then

    iCountFiles  = AttachmentFiles.Count - 1

    For index = 0 To iCountFiles 

        Dim Attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(AttachmentFiles(index))

        If IO.File.Exists(AttachmentFiles(index)) Then _
          email.Attachments.Add(Attachment)
    Next

  End If
```