# Send Logs as an attachment in an email after regular intervals vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, logging

I have a created a vb.net application which generates some logs on the local machine but now I need to send these logs to an email after say every 30 minutes and flush the log file to record new logs and save them. Email is not important here as I am happy if the logs are updated to the FTP server too but how do I manage to send a file after regular intervals and create a new file?

For email I found this which could be helpful: [how to send an email with attachment in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962511/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-in-vb-net)

But struggling to find a way that would manage the logs to sent after 30 mins and then a new log file and no data loss.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into `Scheduled Tasks`. You can run a program at intervals to do what you need done. Look into "common I/O tasks" in MSDN Visual Studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, can you help with this last thing i am stuck here

Using sr As New StreamReader(TextBox3.Text)
            line = sr.ReadToEnd()
        End Using

So this reads the file content and saves it in 'line' but how do I remove the read content from file. textbox3 has the file location typed by the user.

Comment: @rheitzman     please help me